# Thaumcraft troubles

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-thaumcraft

What am I missing here im scanning what im supposed the thaumometer shows picture of the aspects and points the item is made of but im not getting the points in my research table?

On single player I make arcane worktable, research table, wand, thaumometer,Thauminomicon, Scan items get points but on multiplayer server doing things the same way it doesn't work. Im sure its me being dumb but I have been looking on web for answers for a week and have none so if anyone could put me out of my misery that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You only get research points when you scan new things, this is visible by the icons flowing the the top right corner of the screen and the bottom left getting a bunch of "Gained X points for Y".

You can also get research points via later mechanics like deconstruction tables and warp effects.

There are also per research table bonus aspects (1 per type) that you can gain via placing various items around the research table (crystal clusters for the primal aspects, book cases for very slowly getting all the aspects). This is slow but a good bonus pool if you're just short. You will first use the regular points up before the bonus points get used.

Comment: Yeah I did clusters and bookcases around already. I have just only prime aspects and lux discovered. When I scan items it acts as though I have found them before but I haven't I get no points and they are not discovered in research table and book unless I combine aspects like I did with lux.    Thanks for your fast reply

Comment: Hmm, sounds like something weird with your player data on the server, try dumping your inventory in a chest and getting an admin to delete your player.dat file? (after backing up!) That will lose you all the research you done so far though.